# keeping connection string and connection object centrally in c# application

Tags: c#, database, string, class, connection

Im a beginner to C# (.net of course) and for my final year project im developing a payroll system. Now I have some issues regarding ado.net sql connection object.
To keep the connection string centrally I have used a separate class call `db`. Taking another step to this centralization thinking, I've initialized the connection object also centrally in this `db class` as follows.

```
class db
{

string connectionString = ("connection string will be here...");

    public SqlConnection GetConn()
    {
        SqlConnection NewConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        return NewConn;
    }
}
```

Now Im using this connection object as follows in my application...
I just want to know whether I would face issues in future because of this practice and also appreciate if one of experts could explain me what is the best practice in this regard.

Thanks in advance

```
class client
 {

    db NewDB = new db(); // db class is instantiated...
    SqlConnection newCon; // object referece newConn is created...


    //Method to insert new clients to 'client' table

    public void addNewClient(DateTime entDate, client NewClient)
    {
        try
        {
            newCon = NewDB.GetConn(); // connection object is assigned to newCon... but this is optional and I put this for the clarity

            string CommandString = "INSERT INTO client(Client_Name, C_Add, Contact_Person, C_Mob_No, C_Tel_No, Remarks, Ent_Date)" +
                                    " VALUES (@CName, @CAdd, @CPerson, @CMob, @CTel, @Remarks, @entDate)";


            SqlCommand SqlCom = new SqlCommand();
            SqlCom.CommandText = CommandString;
            SqlCom.Parameters.Add("@CName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = NewClient.CName;
            SqlCom.Parameters.Add("@CAdd", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = NewClient.CAdd;
            SqlCom.Parameters.Add("@CPerson", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = NewClient.CPerson;
            SqlCom.Parameters.Add("@CMob", SqlDbType.Char).Value = NewClient.CMob;
            SqlCom.Parameters.Add("@CTel", SqlDbType.Char).Value = NewClient.CTel;
            SqlCom.Parameters.Add("@Remarks", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = NewClient.Remarks;
            SqlCom.Parameters.Add("@entDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = entDate;
            SqlCom.Connection = newCon;
            newCon.Open();

            SqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }

        finally
        {
            newCon.Close(); // newCon object is global to entire class so can call its close method.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use global connection object. Your db connections are stored in connection pool. So you won't run out of connections. [Read more about connections pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. So that Ill build the connection string centrally in db class and connection object will be created in method level.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your client class it is bad practice to write raw SQl in the code. It is better practice to write a stored procedure and call it from the code passing the parameters.

```
public void addNewClient(DateTime entDate, client NewClient)
    {
        try
        {
            newCon = NewDB.GetConn(); // create connection 
            conn.Open(); //open connection 

            // create a command object identifying the stored procedure
            SqlCommand SqlCom = new SqlCommand("Store Procedure name", newConn);

           // add parameter to sql command, which is passed to the stored procedure
           SqlCom .Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CName", NewClient.CName));

          // Rest of parameters

          // execute the command
          cmd.ExecuteReader();
      }
  }
```

Creating a class to store the connection is good practice. However you could expand on this further.

```
public struct slqParameters
{

    public object ParamData { get; set; }
    public string ParamKey { get; set; }
    public SqlDbType ParamDatabaseType { get; set; }
    public int ParamSize { get; set; }
}

class db
{
    private string connectionString = ("connection string will be here...");

    public static void ExecuteStoreProcedure(string ProcedureName, ref slqParameters[]  CommandParameters)
     {
         string str_ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
         try
         {
             using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(str_ConnectionString))
             {
                 using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sProcedureName, sqlConnection) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure })
                 {
                     // Add all the parameters to the sql command.
                     foreach (slqParametersParameter in CommandParameters)
                     {
                         // Add a parameter
                         sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(Parameter.ParamKey, Parameter._ParamDatabaseType , Parameter._ParamSize ) { Value = Parameter.ParamData  });
                        }
                        sqlConnection.Open();
                        DataTable dtTable = new DataTable();
                        sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                throw error;
            }
        }
}
```

This is only a ruff guide as i have not tested it yet but it should work

To use it on your page

```
Public SomeMethod()
{
     slqParameters[] parameters = new Parameters[1]
    {
        new sqlParameters{ ParamData  = , paramKey = "@CName", ParamDatabaseType  = NewClient.CName}
    };

    db.ExecuteStoreProcedure("Store Procedure name", parameters);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and code sample. I think this is the three tire model of development separating data and logic. Is it a good practice to develop OO systems in this way?